# use simplexml_load_string to parse a XML document STREAM

Tags: php, xml

I have a TLS/TCP connection to a server that's serving XML documents as a stream of documents.  At any time, the stream may have:

1. a partial document (e.g. `<doc1>one`)
2. a complete document (e.g. `<doc1>one</doc1>`)
3. a complete document and a partial document (e.g. `<doc1>one</doc1><doc2>`)
4. multiple documents, etc. (e.g. `<doc1>one</doc1><doc2>two</doc2>`)

When I read from the stream, I just append read data to an "unparsed" buffer, then attempt to parse the buffer with `simplexml_load_string`.  (1) is ok (fails), and (2) is ok (works), my problem is, of course, (3) and (4) fail with extra data.  I don't really have a way of saying to the parser "just parse the first X characters" (or use substr) since that would require actually parsing the XML.  The documents are, of course, a lot more complex than the examples.  Is there any way to:

1. make simplexml_load_string ignore the extra data and have it return a document AND the number of characters it consumed from the string (so I can do buffer manipulation), or
2. use some other parser/convention

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to consider using a parser that's designed for streaming, like [XmlReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) or [Xml Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.  Basically, if I use `xml_parser_create` and `xml_parse` and that fails with `Invalid document end` it tells me where it failed via `xml_get_current_byte_index`.  I can then take the `substr` at that point and try it again.  Lack of efficiency aside, it seems to work for all the cases outlined, except for telling if a failure is going to be permanent or not...